# How to add custom Google search to my customized search box?

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine, google-search

So I want to keep the styling of my own Google box, but I want to direct to Google Search of my page.

The code looks something like this:

```
<......>
</ul>
<form action="" method="post" id="FORM_10">
  <div id="DIV_11">
    <link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  id="LINK_12">

    <div id="DIV_14">
        <div id="DIV_15">
          <div id="DIV_16">
            <div id="DIV_17">
              <div id="DIV_18">
                <div id="DIV_19">
                  <div id="DIV_20">
                    <div id="DIV_21">
                      <input value="sdasdsad" id="INPUT_22" name="keys" size="60" maxlength="255" type="text">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <input id="INPUT_44" name="op" value="search" type="submit">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
   </form> <a href="#" id="A_45" title="english">en</a> <a href="#" id="A_46" title="contacts">contacts</a>
    </div>
```

and I would like to somehow add the functionality as if `gcse:search` is present in my code, but I want to remain with my own stylized search box, but when the users inserts his string to the search box, he gets a pop-up overlay window with Google search results on specified site.

Worst case scenario. I would like to find out how can I properly customize the Google search box.

Comment: I use the "results only" CSE option and pass the query string from our search boxes on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has support for "custom" search engines which you can register [here](https://cse.google.com), which allows you to specify domains (and paths) that you want to include in the search (the equivalent of a `site:` parameter in a search):

[image: Google CSE]

Now, for this example, I made a search for `https://developer.mozilla.org`, since their insite search isn't as good as google's. I labeled it `MDN`, and clicked create (after agreeing to the terms of service):

[image: Create the search engine for mozilla]

From here we'll get the source code to use with the `Get Code` button, which will give us an HTML snippet to insert. Mine looked like this:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '005381150112327209486:iwm6p6iff_4';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Insert the script into your `<head>` and place the `<gcse:search>` tag where you want the input to appear. Read about custom styling of these [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element)

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript after the click on the search button you can redirect to the google search results page using this link http://www.google.it/search?q=
you can create the url conatening the search query
For example if you want to search an house you can redirect ti this page http://www.google.it/search?q=house

Comment: This will violate most browser's Same Origin Security Policy. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)